# Does there exist an unbounded projection

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification

It is a well known fact that orthogonal projections are bounded. To define orthogonality an inner product is necessary. For the purpose of this question let's move from this inner product setting into a Banach space setting:

Assume $X$ is a Banach space. Assume $U,V$ are complemented subspaces. Define $p$ in the obvious way so that it is the projection with image $V$ and kernel $U$.

Does it then follow that $p$ is continuous? Believe the answer to be yes but I'm not sure my argument is correct. Could one argue as follows?:

Recall that by the closed graph theorem $p$ is continuous if $X \times p(X)$ is closed in $X \times X$ with the product topology. Note that since $U,V$ are complementary they are closed. Note that $X$ is closed in $X$. Also note that $p(X) = V$ is closed in $X$. Hence $X \times p(X)$ is closed hence $p$ is continuous.

Comment: No. $X\times p(X)\neq \{(x,p(x)):x\in X\}$, so you can't apply closed graph theorem. For the desired proof see proposition 4.2 in [Banach space theory. The basis for linear and non-linear analysis. M. Fabian, P. Habala, P. Hajek, V. Montesinos, V. Zizler](http://bookfi.org/book/1208933)

Comment: @Norbert Thank you very much for your helpful comment!

Comment: @Norbert Hence the answer to the question in the title is: No. And therefore one could suspect that there exists a proof of the boundedness of $p$ that shows that $\|p\|$ is finite (without appealing to the closed graph theorem).

Comment: Yes, it is possbile